# Views display of every user's flagged nodes grouped by flag type

Tags: views, flags

I am using views and the flags module to create a site where users can flag node items  with multiple flags/flag types. For my example, a user can flag nodes (content) items with one of three flags: fruits, veggies, or other.

User 1, name and profile picture

---

```
flag-fruits     flag-veggies     flag-other
------          ------           ------
apple           carrots          pork
orange          celery           ham
cherry                           soda
```

User 2, name and profile picture

---

```
flag-fruits     flag-veggies     flag-other
------          ------           ------
lime            artichoke        trout
banana          lettuce          barley
cherry          ginger           soda
```

User 3, name and profile picture

---

etc…

I have tried setting up the relationships in Views using content (node) item listings and Users' Flagged Content relationships. With Grouping Fields I can manage to relate a single flag type to each user, so…

User 1

---

```
flag-fruits
------
apple
orange
cherry
```

But I really need the view to show each flag under each user in a list. I have been attempting this with the [ViewField][1] module and also regular Views Attachments, but so far with no luck. Is this even possible? Panels maybe?

```
[1]: http://drupal.org/project/viewfield
```

Answer (score 0):

For grouping, I have used [Views Grouped Table](http://drupal.org/project/views_grouped_table) to good effect. You might also look at [Views Complex Grouping](http://drupal.org/project/views_complex_grouping), a more recent module.